# Github UI - cannot edit file further after viewing in preview pane

Tags: github, readme

I want to create a README.md file using the Github edit/preview file interface. 
The problem is when I switch to the Preview pane and then back to the Edit pane, I can see a cursor blinking at the very top of the document but cannot move it or perform any further editing.

If I want to add/modify content I need to cancel the entire operation and start again from scratch. Needless to say, this isn't optimal. Is there something I am missing here? Or is it simply not possible? Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to save the `README` as is.

[Since July 2018](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-07-24-button-to-edit-a-repositorys-readme-from-the-repository-root/), you now have a **button to edit it further**.

> ### Button to edit a repository's `README` from the repository root
>
> If you have permission to push to a repository, you can now edit a `README` file from the repository root by clicking the pen icon to the right of the `README`’s file header.
> Learn more about [editing files in your repositories here](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository/).